# Re-execute a command by a given time interval in bash

Tags: linux, bash, counter, increment

Is there a way to Re-execute a command by a given time interval in bash?
I want Weather to be re-executed every 30 min.
here is example of my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Show time, date and clickable calendar
clock() {
    curtime=`date '+%I:%M'` 
    curdate=`date '+%d-%m-%Y'`
    echo "%{A:/usr/bin/gsimplecal:}%{T2} %{T1}$curdate%{A} %{T2} %{T1}$curtime"
}


volume1() {
    amixer get Master | sed -n 'N;s/^.*\[\([0-9]\+%\).*$/\1/p'
 }

#weather
weather(){
  curl -s "$(curl -s 'http://www.wunderground.com/' | sed -n '/Full Forecast/{s#[^"]*"\([^"]*\)".*#http://www.wunderground.com\1#p}')" | sed -n '/"curCond"/{ s#.*wx-value[^>]*>\([^<]*\)<.*#\1#; h }; /"curTemp"/{ N; N; N; s#.*wx-value[^>]*>\([^<]*\)<.*wx-unit[^>]*>&deg;\(.\).*#\1°\2 #; G; s#\n##; p }'
    echo $weather
    }

while :; do

echo "%{B#DDecf0f1}%{F#2c2c2c}%{T2}%{l}    $(groups)    %{T1}$(curwin) %{r}%{F#2C2C2C}  $(weather) $(space)|$(space) VOL: $(volume1) $(space)|$(space) $(uptime)  $(space)|$(space)   $(clock) %{A2}$(curwin)"

sleep 1 #sleep of mainloop

done
```

Comment: Why not use `cron` or `at`?

Comment: Cron will re-execute whole script? I want to re-execute only "weather" in my script. What is at?

Comment: @LuisVito please show exactly what you want executed every 30 minutes.  Are you trying to execute what is the while loop every 30 minutes, because currently every function call that is in a sub-shell `$()` in your echo statement is getting executed every second. Please clarify even with pseudo code.

Comment: I want to re-execute  "weather" function every 30 min and leave everything else like it is.

Comment: @LuisVito Simplest, just save weather to a file every 30 min via cron, some background process, whatever... Then read from file in your script. Or just save time, check if 30 minutes have passed, and if they have display new weather and update time.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use *cron* to run your script periodically.

If you only want to run a specific function from your script ( e.g. `weather()` ), add a switch statement to your script in which you'll perform a check if a certain option was provided, for example `-w` for executing the `weather()` function.

When you edit *crontab* to run every 30 minutes ( i.e. `0,30 * * * * my_script` ), provide `-w` to your script in order to execute `weather()` only - `0,30 * * * * my_script -w`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try this.

Comment: @LuisVito You're welcome :-) Please let us know if it works for you!